# apply function returns list of lists if run twice

Tags: r

I have a df like this

```
a1 <- c(1,2,NA)
a2 <- c(3,4,NA)
a3 <- c(4,5,6)
a1_fill <- c(1,2,3)
a2_fill <- c(3,4,5)
a3_fill <- c(4,5,6)
b1 <- c(4,3,1)
b2 <- c(2,NA,9)
b3 <- c(NA,3,5)
b1_fill <- c(4,3,1)
b2_fill <- c(2,1,9)
b3_fill <- c(8,3,5)
df <- data.frame(a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,a1_fill,a2_fill,a3_fill,b1_fill,b2_fill,b3_fill)
```

I want to create two new columns with values from the `fill` cols that do not appear in the corresponding `a` or `b` cols. I do so like this

```
df$missingA <- apply(df,1,function(x) setdiff(x[which(grepl("a",names(x),fixed = TRUE) & grepl("fill",names(x),fixed = TRUE))],x[which(grepl("a",names(x),fixed = TRUE) & !grepl("fill",names(x),fixed = TRUE))]))
df$missingB <- apply(df,1,function(x) setdiff(x[which(grepl("b",names(x),fixed = TRUE) & grepl("fill",names(x),fixed = TRUE))],x[which(grepl("b",names(x),fixed = TRUE) & !grepl("fill",names(x),fixed = TRUE))]))
```

For some reason when I run the above code, the line that is run second returns a list of lists, whereas the first returns a list of numeric. Why is this?

Comment: the first lines returns a list as well

Comment: The line that is run second returns a list of lists. I've edited my question to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is dependent on the order in which the lines are run. We can use the code below to determine the class of the elements in the columns

```
class(df$missingA[[1]]) # Class of first element is numeric
class(df$missingB[[1]]) # Class of first element is list
```

Starting from a clean dataset, if you first create missingB and then create missingA, you'll see that the missingA will be a list of list, whereas missingB will be a list of numeric (the types are reversed).

```
df$missingB <- apply(df,1,function(x) 
  setdiff(
    x[which(
      grepl("b",names(x),fixed = TRUE) & 
      grepl("fill",names(x),fixed = TRUE))
    ],
    x[which(
      grepl("b",names(x),fixed = TRUE) & 
      !grepl("fill",names(x),fixed = TRUE))
    ]
  )
)


df$missingA <- apply(df,1,function(x) 
  setdiff(
    x[which(
      grepl("a",names(x),fixed = TRUE) & 
      grepl("fill",names(x),fixed = TRUE))
    ],
    x[which(
      grepl("a",names(x),fixed = TRUE) & 
      !grepl("fill",names(x),fixed = TRUE))
    ]
  )
)

class(df$missingA[[1]]) # Class of first element is list
class(df$missingB[[1]]) # Class of first element is numeric
```

My guess is that the following is happening. You are starting off with a dataframe containing only numeric columns. R tries to be helpful by matching the type of your list to numeric. When the second column gets added the dataframe is no longer
purely made up of numeric columns, as one of the types is now list, and therefore R does not try to update the type.

To test this you can add a none numeric column before adding missingA and missingB for example:

```
df$text <- list("a","b","C")
```

Now missingA and missingB will both be created as list of list

Another way to retain the types as they are produced by the apply statements is by assigning the output to an intermediate variable

```
missingA <- apply(df,1,function(x) 
setdiff(
  x[which(
    grepl("a",names(x),fixed = TRUE) & 
    grepl("fill",names(x),fixed = TRUE))
  ],
  x[which(
    grepl("a",names(x),fixed = TRUE) & 
    !grepl("fill",names(x),fixed = TRUE))
  ]
 )
)

df$missingA <- missingA
```

To summarize, the difference you are seeing is not caused by the apply statements or the output they produce, but by how the data is added to the dataframe. Hope this helps!